# Web Services using J2ME and Java Version 1.4

Tags: java, service, mtom, jdk1.4

We are trying to program an MFP (Multi-function-printer) to communicate to our backend using Web Services. We are sending large images so using MTOM is important. Since we are dealing with a very constrained environment I would rather not use Axis. Does anyone know of another smaller WS library that will work with JDK1.4, or would it be better to 'Roll our own'?

Answer (score 0):

AXIS comes with J2ME implementation of JSR 172,

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/webservices/axis/trunk/contrib/j2me/

But I doubt it supports MTOM.